# How to filter the data for JDE object browser in date format?

Tags: jdedwards, enterpriseone

I am new user for JDE and JDE Data browser as well. But for what I know the JDE data browser only enables us to do create some filter condition for our data.

Let say I wish to get the data in a range of dates (Example:20/11/2009 To 8/9/2012).

What comment should I put on JDE Data browser? or the JDE data browser didn't support this function?

Comment: Is there a good reason that yours is the only question visible on the front-page that is so rude as to be in ALL CAPS?

Comment: very sorry to say i just realize about it. Usually i name my project name with block letter.And i forget to turn off the CapsLock No offense~

Comment: Easily enough mistake to make. No offence caused. You should have better luck getting a solution now. I'd help but am less experienced in JDE than you (about to google what the elephant it is)

Comment: thxz enhzflep. I google it already and the result i get is not what i wan.(T.T)

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. I was saying that I know _nothing_ about JDE, and that **I** had to google it. It certainly wasn't a suggestion that _you_ goggle it. :)

Comment: o ic~sorry about it.However thxz for ur help....(^^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JDE Data browser nor the UTB have that capability. You could achieve this only if you had the field two times in your table. It could be achieved via SQL, but then you would have to face data conversion since JDE store data differently that what it display (dates are stored in julian format).

So the answer to your question: you cannot query a date range on one column in the data browser.

Work around: query via SQL, but you will have data conversion to do.

have a good day